# Porting .NetCore VS2015 to VS2017 Referencing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

After porting a .net core web solution from vs2015 to vs2017 I receive the following error at runtime, and am having difficulty finding the missing reference.

> 'IHtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationInsightsJavaScript' and no extension method 'ApplicationInsightsJavaScript' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>       @Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration)

I have made a reference to **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights(2.2.0)** and **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore(2.0.0)**

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Was also updating 2015 to 2017. But my issue started appearing after updating ApplicationInsights to 2.0.0.

I solved it by replacing in _ViewImports.cshtml: 
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration TelemetryConfiguration 
with: 
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet

And replacing in _Layout.cshtml:
@Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration) 
with: 
@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)

Hope it helps